# Does arcpy have a tool for converting file geodatabase Table to JSON?

Tags: arcpy, json

arcpy has:

```
arcpy.FeaturesToJSON_conversion()
```

which can handle feature layers, but what about file geodatabase **tables**?

Not too hard to implement custom, but I want something with the same API as FeaturesToJSON and will be maintained by Esri as updates are made.  Here is a custom solution, but I don't like it:

```
def feature_table_to_json(tablePath, fields='*'):
    rows = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tablePath, field_names=fields) as cursor:
        print cursor.fields
        colnames = cursor.fields
        for row in cursor:
            rows.append(dict(zip(colnames, row)))
    date_converter = lambda r: r.isoformat() if isinstance(r, datetime.datetime) else None
    result = {}
    result['features'] = rows
    return json.dumps(result, default=date_converter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, but the final JSON have to be small enough fit in memory (though your sample script has that same restriction). [The `RecordSet` object has a .JSON property](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000027000000) so you can roll your own that way too:

```
r = RecordSet(tablePath)
with open('out.json', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.JSON)
```